# tinybutstrong stop showing [var.myvariable] in loaded page when variable is not set

Tags: tinybutstrong

I have an html page that is being rendered with the template engine tinybutstrong.

The problem I have found is that if I have a variable that is not set in the php file, when the page loads, it shows

[var.myvariable]

is there a way to stop this without having to declare all variables in the php file

i.e.

$myvariable = '';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use parameter `noerr` on each TBS field that you'd like to force the merging without error.

```
[var.myvariable;noerr]
```